# ASP.NET MVC 4 Authentication with an existing user database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC framework. I'm asked to develop an application using MVC 4

Our company already has an authentication table in DB2.The columns are Employee ID, Name, Security ID,  etc.

How can i develop an application witch uses that table for authentication

Answer (score 5):

Actually, for MVC 4, [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx) is better.  The MVC 3/4 link ignores some advances made in MVC 4 (e.g. the built in 'AuthorizeAttribute').